# Url Rewriting of once controller - cake 2.0

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting, routes, cakephp-2.0

I'm developing a simple CMS in CakePHP, right now it has 4 controllers in it(Menus,Site,Roles,Users), I want to rewrite one controller, but I'm having problem.

I use all the actions only as admins for admin purpose like admin_view, admin_add......
except siteController(this controller is only for frontend purpose)

I need my www.example.com/site/view/something_here must be replaced to www.example.com/something_here - this will be displayed in front-end so.

I added a line in my routes file:

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'site', 'action' => 'view'));
```

But after adding this I couldn't able to use other controllers.

I again added some more lines before the above line:

```
Router::connect('/admin/Menus/*', array('controller' => 'menus', 'prefix' => 'admin'));
```

Same for all other controllers, but if I send any action or id in url it doesn't works.
like - http://www.exmple.com/admin/menus/[view/1] - the one inside square bracket doesn't works.

any Ideas on rewriting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered a similar question on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213814/cakephp-route-with-regex/10217203#10217203).

To put the admin controller routes before the '/*'-route was the right idea, but the way you did it the router can't assign an action. You could use the following for each controller:

```
Router::connect('/admin/Menus/:action/*', array('controller' => 'menus', 'prefix' => 'admin'));
```

Or you could use the [default prefix-routing routes](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/950/Prefix-Routing), so you don't have to add a route for each new controller.

```
// prefix routing default routes with admin prefix
Router::connect("/admin/:controller", array('action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
Router::connect("/admin/:controller/:action/*", array('prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
```